# check string valid or not in PHP

Tags: php, string

How to know which word has valid id card with criterion? If id card has 10 characters or more then id card is valid otherwise it is not valid.

example of sentences :

```
$String_1 = "i'm john and my id card 12334435345 my favorite team xxxxxxxx.";

$String_2 = "i'm ananda ramadina and my id card 9090909889 my favorite team YYYYYYYYYY.";

$String_3 = "i'm dinda rahayu and my id card 909 my favorite team RRRRRRRR.";
```

Comment: Without code, we can't help you.Share your code stuff here and explain more what you have to try to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your card id string is always after the "card" word into the string you can try this code:

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $String_1);

$cardId = $pieces[array_search('card', $pieces)+1];

if (strlen ( $cardId ) > 10)
{
   // Ok
}
else 
{
   // Ko
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
$id = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// compare the length for $id
if (strlen($id) < 10) // not valid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
$string_1 = "i'm john and my id card 125345 my favorite team xxxxxxxx.";

/* using regex to match string */
preg_match("/id card ([0-9]*)?/", $string_1, $output_array);

/* this will assign $getNumber the value of $output_array[1] if it exists, otherwise a blank value */
$getNumber = isset($output_array[1]) ? $output_array[1] : "";

if(strlen($getNumber) >= 10) {
    echo "valid";
} else { 
    echo "invalid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$String_1 = "i'm john and my id card 12334435345 my favorite team xxxxxxxx.";
$intVal = filter_var($String_1, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$count = strlen($intVal);
if ($count >= 10) {
// some logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if in your string only card number then use `filter_var` with `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`

```
$String_1 = "i'm john and my id card 112312312312312 my favorite team xxxxxxxx.";
$card_number = filter_var($String_1, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// compare the length for $card_number 
if (strlen($card_number) < 10){
    echo 'invalid';
} else {
   echo 'valid';
}
```

you can use this code if in your string have 2 or many number type

```
$String_1 = "i'm john and my id card 1 my favorite team xxxxxxxx.";
$get_card_info = explode('id card', $String_1);

$get_card_format = explode('my favorite', $get_card_info[1]);

if (strlen($get_card_format[0]) > 10) {
    echo 'valid';
} else {
    echo 'not valid';
}
```